# What's the id generation strategy used in Grails unit test

Tags: grails

I have used default id generation strategy in my app (with postgres), and I have a unique sequence table in my db for all my other tables, so an id has to be unique in my table space.

However, I don't have the same behavior in my unit tests, because I have the same id in different tables, I guess that Grails use a different strategy in test? (a sequence per table?)

thanks

Comment: grails uses a test environment while testing, refer DataSource.groovy. By default the DB is in memory h2 unless otherwise you have changed it to something else. The sequence in Postgres does not apply here in h2.

Comment: Complementing: if Postgres will be always your prod database I suggest you to use another Postgres base to the integration tests, this will allow you to identify possible issues before hitting production.

Answer (score 0):

By default grails rollbacks DB transactions in the unit / integration tests. That may explain the odd behavior.

You can try to make the unit tests non transactional by explicitly stating that in the Test class.

```
static transactional = false
```